# Calling a class function inside of another function in the same class

Tags: javascript, function, class

I'm trying to do something in Javascript where I call a return function inside of another function, all within a class, it goes something like this:

```
class MyClass {
 constructor (x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }

 newValues () {
  this.x = findNextXValue(this.x);
 }

 findNextXValue (x) {
  let changeVal = x + 5;
  return changeVal;
 }

}
```

When I try this code in p5js I get an error saying that findNextXValue is not defined. Why can't I do something like this? Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where do you think `findNextXValue` is defined?  (It isn't defined in your example code.)

Comment: Class methods exist on the object (or prototype), they're not standalone identifiers - put `this.` in front

Comment: I just realized that maybe I missed the problem that I am actually facing - I am trying to do an if statement within the newValues() function that says something like if (findNextXValue(this.x) > 20) { this.x = 20 }

Answer (score 0):

Missing this should be...

```
this.findNextXValue(this.x);
```

But you really don't need to pass this.x either. Just access this.x in the function.

Comment: Thank you. I think what I'm trying to do is working now.